# Multiple Variables and Macros

Tags: macros, sas

I hope someone maybe able to help me. I have some quite lengthy SQL code which extracts out several bits of information including sales and web data. I need to run this for multiple cities. However rather than re-run the code multiple times, manually changing the city each time. I wondered if I could use macros so that the code is only written once however the city is a macro variable of some kind and when the code is run, it reads down say a table of the cities of interest, the output would be a table for each one.

To put things into context, below is an extract of the code where you can see the variable 'City' which is 'London' for this example.

```
rsubmit;
proc sql; 
    create table help as 
        select distinct a.customer_id, max(a.level) as level, a.london
            from (
                select distinct customer_id, max(SESSION_DT) as session_dt format date9., TXT,
                    case when TXT in ('Gold') then 1
                         when TXT in ('Silver') then 2
                         when TXT in ('Bronze') then 3
                         else 4 end as level,
                    case when customer_id is not null then "3" else '' end as London
                        from search_data
                            where CITY in ('London') and TXT is not null
                                group by 1) a
group by 1;
quit;
endrsubmit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You sure can put strings of city names into a macro variable and then parse them out, however, it will come with the length limitation of 64K bytes as well as the complexity of macro programming. Here is what I would do in this context:
1. Put your main code into a Macro
2. Put all of your city names into a SAS table.
3. Use CALL EXECUTE ( ) to call for the macro dynamically.

```
%macro test(city=London);
rsubmit;
proc sql; 
    create table help as 
        select distinct a.customer_id, max(a.level) as level, a.london
            from (
                select distinct customer_id, max(SESSION_DT) as session_dt format date9., TXT,
                    case when TXT in ('Gold') then 1
                         when TXT in ('Silver') then 2
                         when TXT in ('Bronze') then 3
                         else 4 end as level,
                    case when customer_id is not null then "3" else '' end as London
                        from search_data
                            where CITY eq "&city." and TXT is not null
                                group by 1) a
group by 1;
quit;
endrsubmit;
%mend;

data _null_;
set cities; /*this is where you store city names in a variable named CITY, one per row*/
call execute ('%test (city= '||city ||')' );
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's helped. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, you can accomplish what you want in one SQL step rather than trying to loop through city using macros:

```
proc format;
    value $level.
        'Gold' = 1
      'Silver' = 2
      'Bronze' = 3
         other = 4
         ;

      value customer_city
              . = ''
          other = 3
             ;

run;

proc sql;
    create table help as
    select
       distinct customer_id
     , city
     , max(session_id) as session_id
     , max(put(TXT, $level.)) as level
     , put(customer_id, customer_city.) as customer_city
    from search_data
    where TXT is not null
    group by customer_id, city
    ;
quit;
```

Here "customer_city" would take the place of what you had as "a.London", "a.Tokyo" etc

Without a description of your "search_data" and an example of your desired output, I can't say with confidence this code will do exactly what you want - it may even have some errors as it stands. But you should be able to modify it appropriately and do all the summaries in one step.

In your approach, SQL loops through search_data once, and then loops through the aggregated data once more. Then you will have to do this for every different city you have. In other words, the number of times you will scan the data set is approximately 2*Number of Cities. If search_data is large, this will be a lot slower than doing this in one SQL step.

If you really need a separate table for each city, then you can split them with this macro:

```
%macro subset_city(data, city);

   data &city._table(rename=(customer_city=&city.));
       set &data.;

       where city = &city.;
    run;

%mend subset_city;

data _null_;
    set list_of_cities;

     call execute ('%subset_cities(data =help, city= '||city ||')');
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. That's helped my understanding. I really appreciate it.